# How do you update an existing svg element with the d3v5 join syntax

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to make a heatmap where the x and y cell values can remain constant however the "fill" attribute can change based on the data. I tried to do something like this:

```
var tiles = svg.selectAll('rect')
            .data(data.values, function(d) {return d.mt_aa+':'+d.position_aa;})


// set up the enter/update/exit block
tiles.join(
    function(enter) {              
        return enter
        .append("rect")                                      
        .attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.mt_aa) })                         // set x coordinate
        .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.position_aa) })                   // set y coordinate
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )                                       // set tile width
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )                                      // set tile height
        .style("fill", function(d) {return myColor(d.score) })               // set tile fill based on viridis pallete
        .style("opacity", 0);                                                // set opacity as 0 so elements are added but not visible
    },
    function(update) {
      return update
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)                                                      
        .attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.mt_aa) })                      
        .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.position_aa) })                  
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )                                   
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )                                    
        .style("fill", function(d) {return myColor(d.score) })               
        .style("opacity", 0);
    },
    function(exit){                                         
        return exit
        .transition()                                                 
        .duration(1000)
        .style('opacity', 0)                                         
        .on('end', function() {                                              
            d3.select(this).remove();
        });
    }
  )
  .transition()                                                
  .duration(1000)
  .style("opacity", 1);
```

This mostly works, transitions appropriately, etc., but only if one or more of the heatmap cells are new. If I pass through data where nothing changes but the fill (d.score) nothing transitions/updates. I suspect this is occurring because nothing is being added or removed and so as far as d3 is concerned nothing needs to be updated and the update block never executes. However I'm unsure how to go about solving this using the join syntax in d3 v5.

**Updated** with the working answer suggested by @anbnyc

```
// create tiles with 'rect' elements
var tiles = svg.selectAll('rect')                                               // from our svg select the rectangle elements, important for the enter/update/exit block below
            .data(data.values, function(d) {return d.mt_aa+':'+d.position_aa;}) // bind the data to the rect selection
            
const t = svg.transition()
             .duration(1000);

// set up the enter/update/exit block
tiles.join(
    enter => enter    
        .append("rect")                                                      
        .attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.mt_aa) })                       
        .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.position_aa) })                  
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )                                       
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )                                     
        .style("fill", function(d) {return myColor(d.score) })              
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .call(enter => enter.transition(t)
                            .style("opacity", 1)),
    update => update                                                  
        .attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.mt_aa) })                      
        .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.position_aa) })                  
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )                                   
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .call(update => update.transition(t)
                              .style("fill", function(d) {return myColor(d.score) })               
                              .style("opacity", 1)),
    exit => exit
            .style('opacity', 0)
            .call( exit => exit.transition(t)
            .remove())
  )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `update` function needs to return a selection, but it's currently returning a transition. Use `.call` to apply a transition to a selection inside `join`. See examples at https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join